# given a superclass pointer to an object, how to get the object's size?

Tags: c++, inheritance, sizeof

Say I have a class Foo, and subclasses of it Bar1, Bar2, and Bar3.  The subclasses may add extra fields.

In effect I want a `sizeof()` that works for a Foo*, whether it be an object of the base class or of any of the subclasses.

Clearly I could make my own `SizeOf()` method, and require all subclasses (that add fields) to override this to return the updated `SizeOf()`.  But that's not pretty, it requires work, and it'd probably lead to confusing bugs if you forgot to override the method, or overrode but accidentally had the wrong `sizeof()`.  (For instance, implement `Bar2::Sizeof() { return sizeof( Foo ); }` ).  Is there a superior way?

I'm hoping to use C++17 for this project but would be interested in discussion for any C++ edition.

Comment: `sizeof()` is compile time and you have dynamically (runtime) created objects so no.

Comment: Many thanks Richard but no-where did I say I have to, want to, or even think I can use sizeof(), excepting in a virtual method.

Comment: What do you want to do with a type-erased `sizeof()`? Maybe there's a more elegant way to tackle the larger problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of getting the size if the dynamic type of an object given a base pointer as far as I know.

You could create an associative map from `std::type_index` to the size and use `typeid` to get the `std::type_index` from the base pointer. The remaining work is to make sure that each derived type is added to the map.

An approach that minimises the amount of work per class is to create a class template that has a static member with a constructor that adds the argument type into the map. That way all that the programmer has to remember when creating a new derived type in order to support this feature is to instantiate that template with the new type as template argument.

Comment: I don't like the map but love the template.  I don't like the map because I already have a pointer to the thing and should be able to get info about it with just a pointer deref or two, not the overhead of hash tables or RB-trees or what have you.  But I think a template could set a static int member without the subclasser needing to remember to do that and do it without type, right?  In which case p->iMySize or similar would work.